# Loading a new JavaScript file on new html page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a script that displays an alert when my page loads, but it's not working. What have I done wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
   <div>
         <label> Hi, Welcome to the movie page </label>
   </div>

<style href="js/movie.js"></style>
</body>


</html>
```

The movie.js file:

```
window.addEventListener("load", sayHi);

  function() sayHi
   {
    alert("hi")
   }
```

Comment: An important note, you have your `script` tag set as a `style` tag. `<style href="js/movie.js"></style>`

Comment: In addition to @CupofJava's observation, script tags have a src attribute, not an href (e.g. `<script src="js/movie.js"></script>`)

Answer (score 1):

When defining a function, the syntax is

```
function fnName (...) {...}
```

Instead of:

```
function (...) fnName {...}
```

Because the second one defines an anonymous function which does nothing.

Comment: So the function (...) should contain the parameter being passed right?

Comment: @Aadn You should use `function sayHi() {...}`